# write characters from right to left in aspx

Tags: html, asp.net, right-to-left

Hello everyone I am writing a web app in aspx, My site language is Hebrew (characters from right to left), Is there a special code I need to insert to do so?

Comment: +1'd to correct the down vote as there is no reason, that I can see, to downvote. Please provide an explanation to do so. Welcome to the site. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS direction property for this.

```
div {
    direction:rtl;
}
```

Here's an example: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_text_direction

Comment: @Oded: It's just a link to the "do-it-yourself" example, to demonstrate.

Comment: @Oded: Good to know though - I thought there was some affiliation.

Answer (score 1):

You can add to the body a `dir="rtl"` attribute.

See the [dir attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-dir-attribute) on w3.

Comment: It looks like I was mistaken according to W3, but the correct syntax is `dir="rtl"`

Answer (score 1):

The **Panel control has a [Direction property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.direction.aspx)** which you could use for this when you want to keep it all in ASP.NET itself. Another alternative, better one as it separates layout from the rendered out html is CSS:

```
direction: rtl;
```

For more information please look at the [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#direction).